# How to animate width of multiple elements using animate()

Tags: jquery

I found this website very amazing. I have been studying how they make the animation work with jQuery and CSS3.

This is the website : [SIDIGITAL](http://www.sidigital.co)

The basic idea is that they have a set of connected div. Each of the div has its own absolute position value like top, left relative to its parent and also its own width and height. This is what it is like

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="tube1"><div class="water"></div></div>
    <div class="tube2"><div class="water"></div></div>
    <div class="tube3"><div class="water"></div></div>
</div>
```

You can see that there is another div with the class "water" inside each div. I try to animate the width of the "water" div from 0% to 100% to make it feel like the water is flowing through the tube in 5000 millisecond like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.pipe1 .water').animate({
        width: "100%"
    }, 5000);
});

if('.pipe1 .water').width() = "100%") {
    $('.pipe2 .water').animate({
        width: "100%"
    }, 5000);
}
```

I want the water in the second tube to flow once the width of the water element is 100% and then the water in the tube3.

The current solution works with only the first element which is tube1.

Is there anyway to achieve this?

Comment: if condition check with == or ===. `if('.pipe1 .water').width() = "100%") `

Comment: $ missing `if($('.pipe1 .water').width() == "100%") {`